# Multiple barplots on one page?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I try to do the same thing as in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14118/drawing-multiple-barplots-on-a-graph-in-r with this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/14126/24144

My data looks like this:

```
         q        r        t       s       p
a        757279  1414469   579865  527819  5951
b fa     4311006  5505875 10695932 5658172 63406
c wad    6479734  8194529  1490696 3154758 48312
```

And I want the rows on the x-axis and the columns on the y-axis. I tried using

```
df_t <- t(df)
df_t$id <- 1:nrow(df_t)
# Warning message:
#In distributions_t$id <- 1:nrow(distributions_t) : Coercing LHS to a list
dat <- melt(df_t,id.vars = "id")

ggplot(dat,aes(x=factor(id), y = value)) + 
  facet_wrap(~variable) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = factor(id)))
```

but this gives the error

```
Error in layout_base(data, vars, drop = drop) : 
  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting
```

How can I get the results from this answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/14126/24144?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do as follows (full script for reproducibility);

```
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(q=c(757279, 4311006, 6479734), 
                 r=c(1414469, 5505875, 8194529), 
                 t=c(579865, 10695932, 1490696), 
                 s=c(527819, 5658172, 3154758), 
                 p=c(5951, 63406, 48312), 
                 row.names=c('a', 'b fa', 'c wad'))
df_t <- as.data.frame(t(df))
df_t$id <- 1:nrow(df_t)
dat <- melt(df_t,id.vars = "id")

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=factor(id), y=value)) +
     geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
     facet_wrap(~variable)
p
```

[image: ggplot result]

Comment: That's great, but when I have more than one row only the lowest row shows the x-axis labels, do you know how to fix that?

Comment: @NiekdeKlein use `facet_wrap(~variable,  scales='free')` (honestly, you should check the ggplot2 documentation; a [quick google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=ggplot2+facet_wrap) lead me to [the answer](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/facet_wrap.html))